# text search with two parameters

Tags: php, sql

The user should input two strings and the script will performe a text search:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE name='%$str1%' AND MATCH (street, city, pin) AGAINST ('$hrtg'IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

somehow the % does not work, but it alwas did actually. please help?

Comment: that's terrible combination - indexless LIKE and fulltext index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use % I think you need LIKE statement

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp):

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$str1%'
```

Using `=` will only find strings that exactly match `'%$str1%'`, including the `%` signs.

---

Be careful, your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can use [*prepared statements*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and *bind variables* instead. When using MySQL you should at least use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) to escape your variables.